# Trying to get three divisions side by side

Tags: css, html

Here is my current code but i don't see what the problem is. I'm new to html so i'm not really sure. I'd like to have a column on the left at about 20% space, column in the center which takes 60% of the space and column on the right that takes 20% space.

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #788D9A;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}

#mainleft {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ABB8C0;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    border-right: solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}

#maincenter {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    display:inline-block;


}

#mainright {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ABB8C0;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    border-right: solid black;

}
```

Comment: and it's not working... how?

Comment: Your borders are probably what's messing you up. Add `box-sizing: border-box` (with vendor prefixes) to containers that have a border. The padding also affects it, use percentages for them and remove that percentage from the width.

Comment: What is up with the padding and margins? Do you even know what they are?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be mindful when using `padding-left` `padding-right` `margin-left` `margin-right` `border-left` and `border-right` when you want that type of layout.

Each of those styles affect the overall width of that element so adding a `padding: 10px` will actually make your `div` `width` = `20% + 20px`.

---

If you want to have that inner padding and border style an inner `div`

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b62Ju/2/**

---

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">    
    <div id="mainleft">
        <div>L</div>
    </div>
    <div id="maincenter">
        <div>C</div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainright">
        <div>R</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #788D9A;
}

#wrapper > div
{
    height: 1000px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

#mainleft {
    width: 20%;    
    background-color: #ABB8C0;
}

#maincenter {
    width: 60%;
}

#mainright {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #ABB8C0;
}

#maincenter > div
{    
    height: 1000px;
    border-left: solid black;
    border-right: solid black;
}

#mainleft > div, 
#maincenter > div,
#mainright > div
{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

---

Alternatively you could use the `box-model` styles:

```
.box
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

more info: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Comment: Ahh ok this is where i was going wrong i wasn't taking the padding and borders into consideration. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @cimmanon, unless you do % padding and deduct that from the column width you're in the same boat.

Comment: Are you sure?  The fiddle in my answer says otherwise.

Comment: @cimmanon, just looked at your answer, not a bad solution. I guess if you don't care about IE6 and IE7 (which I don't) that's a clean way to go.

That said, I usually reusing these types of column layouts so having the padding/margin/border on them isn't something I slap on them anyway. I'll throw you a +1.

Answer (score 1):

The `display: table` properties seem like the best choice here.  You get your equal height columns (I assume that's what the crazy bottom margin/padding was for), no extra markup, and padding without having to worry about adjusting the box-model (learn more about the box-model here:  http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

http://jsfiddle.net/b62Ju/3/

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper > div
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
}

#mainleft {
    width: 20%;    
    background-color: orange;
}

#maincenter {
    width: 60%;    
}

#mainright {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your Reference if we need to place three dives side by side,

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">...</div>
    <div class="center">...</div>
    <div class="right">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.left {
    width : 20%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.right {
    width : 20%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.center {
    width : 60%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

it will work.

I think in your code you need set width for main wrapper div.

Comment: you might add that any padding or borders should be used inside the cols, not in the main/left/right classes